# Android Service failing to be started

Tags: android, service

For some reason, the service is not started, none of my debug logs are being called, nor are the toasts I created within the service being shown (Toasts displayed via a handler, toast code not shown, simple guide here for reference: http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/09/show-toast-notification-from-service.html)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Intent locationPollingIntent;
Button updateLocationButton;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationPollingIntent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);

        updateLocationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.updateLocationButton);
        updateLocationButton.setText("Start");

        updateLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, updateLocationButton.getText().toString());

                if (updateLocationButton.getText().toString() == "Start") {
                    MainActivity.this.startService(locationPollingIntent);
                    updateLocationButton.setText("Stop");

                } else if (updateLocationButton.getText().toString() == "Stop") {
                    MainActivity.this.stopService(locationPollingIntent);
                    updateLocationButton.setText("Start");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

A snippet from my Service class looks like so:

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.d(TAG, "Location service started");

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting Service" );
        grabLocation();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    // No implementation
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
```

Lastly, my manifest contains the following

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rperryng.intellilocation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service
            android:name=".LocationService"
            android:label="Location Service" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.rperryng.intellilocation.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It is also worth noting that my mainActivity is in a package `com.rperryng.intellilocation.activities` and my service in `com.rperryng.intellilocation.backgroundServices`

I found the following log that is probably related to the issue:

```
01-27 12:53:58.804: W/ActivityManager(262): Unable to start service Intent {     cmp=com.rperryng.intellilocation/.backgroundServices.LocationService }: not found
```

Comment: Don't use `==` in String comparision, use `equals()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the full package name in your manifest `android:name="com.rperryng.intellilocation.backgroundServices.LocationService"`

Comment: Had tried this, returns a null pointer exception when calling startservice with the intent

Comment: The `MainActivity.this` if weird, why not simply `startService(locationPollingIntent);`?

Comment: I've had run in issues with calling methods from within onClick and other similar methods, but you're right, I guess in this case since no context is relevant it's unnecessary.  After removing them nothing has changed.

Comment: Turns out you were right.  The nullpointer exception i was receving was based on something i was handling in the oncreate method for the service.